# Compiling a groovy scripts that come from a Database

Tags: groovy

Groovy scripts are placed in a Database entry (data type BLOB). I can read the bytes and convert to a String object. How can I use GroovyClassLoader or GroovyScriptEngine to compile and execute the script? I need to track dependencies between scripts so that if any dependent script is modified, the whole tree will be recompiled and reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you take the text to string `scriptAsString`

```
Eval.me(scriptAsString)
```

Perhaps you should store the script(s) as bytecode so you can use them with `classLoader` and make sure dependent scripts are up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

extends GroovyClassLoader overeide  loadClass(), and add your implemetation

```
@Override
    public Class loadClass(String name, boolean lookupScriptFiles,
            boolean preferClassOverScript) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            CompilationFailedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        Class<?> loadedClass = super.loadClass(name, lookupScriptFiles, preferClassOverScript);
        if (loadedClass !=null) {
            return loadedClass;
        }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {

        }

         int indx = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            String substr = name;
            if (indx != -1)
            {
                substr = name.substring(indx + 1);
            }
            String groovyFileName =  substr + ".groovy";
            String path = "C:\\" + groovyFileName;

            try
            {
                return parseClass(new File(path).toString(), groovyFileName);
            }
            catch (CompilationFailedException exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Compiling "main" source from database etc is easy. But problem is when this script imports other. I intensively search solution to compile it "in fly", without success. Class GroovyResourceLoader knows what import is required (I check it, good) but I can't resolve next problems.

Comment: I receive very good answer (plus my own tests) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033980/how-compile-groovy-source-but-not-from-filesystem